# RemoveClass AddClass When Page Load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have several `<div>` tags with different class names.
When the page loads, I want to remove and add another class in a certain `<div>`, but somehow it doesn't work as expected.

[LIVE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/p8snuxfc/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="redBG">
    <div class="yellowIcon"></div>
</div>   
<div class="greenBG">
    <div class="yellowIcon"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.redBG{
    background-color:red;
    width: 300px;
    height:30px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.yellowIcon{
    background-color:yellow;
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index:20;
}
.greenBG{background-color:green}

.black{background-color:black}
```

JS

```
$('div, .redBG').load(
    function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass('.redBG').addClass('.black');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In jQuery, .load is for loading data from a server and inserting it into an element: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Here's jQuery for the page load and changing the classes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.redBG').removeClass('redBG').addClass('black');
});
```

Also, don't use a period for the class when using removeClass and addClass.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/15jg5hbn/

Comment: Oh, thank you very  much, Darren!  It works well.